# Gems é do Ruby ou do On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Estou iniciando em Ruby e On Rails. Fiquei um pouco confuso com relação ao "gem", ele faz parte do Ruby ou do On Rails?

Exemplo de comando abaixo.

```
gem install nome gema
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gem são códigos Ruby empacotados para serem distribuídos e serem reutilizados por outros projetos, apps e etc... Da mesma maneira que são os pacotes `JAR` em **Java** ou como a `Pecl` do **PHP**.

O **RubyGems** é o gerenciador desses pacotes aonde você poderá procurar pela gem que precisa podendo fazer o download direto no seu projeto com o bundle e o gemfile.

Portanto, gems são do Ruby (a linguagem de programação), enquanto o Rails é o Framework Web criado com Ruby (e que por sinal, também é uma gem, ou metagem Ruby).